# force the code to keep running after page closes

Tags: php

i have a While loop (function) that works for several minutes , sometimes it can take up to 10 minutes and sometimes for 30 minutes.

i don't want to let the user wait with the web-page window open for 30 minutes , i want to let the user close the window and let the loop continue by it self.

i want the user to open the web page click on a button to start the function and then close the page and let the function work by it self.

is there any chance anything like that is possible?

Comment: This can be done by calling `exec('php somescript.php')` cause called from command line scripts have no timeout. But... don't do this.

Comment: IF he has access to exec, then he probably has unlimited timeout and browser(in my experience) does not affect the script. If I close the page, the script successfuly continues on itself.

Comment: @lukas.pukenis afair timeout has effect when php is being used with apache (or whatewer), but not when via cli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If script timeout (`max_execution_time` setting in `php.ini`) is no issue for you, you could use **[`ignore_user_abort(true)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)**.

But usually the better solution for such tasks is to spawn them in the background. The **[Gearman](http://php.net/gearman)** extension might be of interest for you, or the different variants of `exec`.

Comment: i think ignore_user_abort is good enough to reach the kind of task im looking for. but why u said that gearman is a better solution?

Comment: it gives you more control over the tasks, you can poll for their status (i.e. with subsequent AJAX requests), you can distribute them to multiple workers, even to remote machines (great for scalability), they need not to run as apache/web user...

Answer (score 3):

You could check out [`fastcgi_finish_request()`](http://php-fpm.org/wiki/Features#fastcgi_finish_request.28.29). It allows for your script to keep running but "hang up" the connection with the browser. It should be used carefully of course, otherwise you may risk having many processes running in the semi-background.

Of course, this is only available with php-fpm. Otherwise you would be looking at stuff like [`gearman`](http://gearman.org/), basically any kind of task scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

User action does not cause the script to stop or so.

The script will continue until it's finished or reaches timeout(on most servers it's 15 or 30 seconds), so if you have your own server or a private one without a timeout, your script will run for 30 minutes with user having no effect on it.

What you should be concerned about - not letting the script to run again if user refreshes the page or visits again within the time frame.

Comment: "User action does not cause the script to stop or so." - oh, it does.

Comment: In my experience - no. That's why in case of infinite loop I can see a timeout in logs despite leaving the page.

Comment: It depends. To quote the docs: "PHP will not detect that the user has aborted the connection until an attempt is made to send information to the client. "

Answer (score 0):

```
function execInBackground($cmd) { 
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
    } 
    else { 
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
    } 
}
```

Or an db + cron solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar in the past.

```
class Task {
  function add($command)
  function execute();
}

class TaskManager {
  function run(){
    $task->execute();
  }
}
```

Tasks are added to a queue (DB, flatfile, carved in stone, whatever you like) as a script or a shell command.  Then TaskManager runs as a service (some good comments at http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) and keeps taking the first item from the queue and executing it.

This way you can service long running tasks in the background and you don't have a lot of rogue processes kicking off.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rethink why you are running such long processes on the front-end like this.  Why not put a work queue in place and let a background daemon or service process then as fast as it can.

What happens currently if t oo many people have open processes and php can't spool up any new threads?

What happens when errors occur or when you need to retry processing?